# Nmap script execution to detect heartbleed is failing

Tags: scripting, ssl, nmap, vulnerability

Wanting to setup Nmap on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system to detect HeartBleed vulnerability. I followed the instructions here:

http://cyberarms.wordpress.com/2014/04/20/detecting-openssl-heartbleed-with-nmap-exploiting-with-metasploit/

To create the script files and place them in the proper directory. However the script throws an execution error.

```
 <error>
 |_ssl-heartbleed: ERROR: Script execution failed (use -d to debug)
 </error>
```

So I ran it with -d to debug and get this:

```
 <error>
 NSE: Starting ssl-heartbleed against "testsite".com (IP Address:443).
 Initiating NSE at 08:28
 NSE: ssl-heartbleed against testsite.com (IP Address:443) threw an error!
 /usr/bin/../share/nmap/scripts/ssl-heartbleed.nse:77: variable 'keys' is not declared
 stack traceback:
 [C]: in function 'error'
 /usr/bin/../share/nmap/nselib/strict.lua:80: in function '__index'
 /usr/bin/../share/nmap/scripts/ssl-heartbleed.nse:77: in function 'testversion'
 /usr/bin/../share/nmap/scripts/ssl-heartbleed.nse:232: in function </usr/bin/../share/nmap/scripts/ssl-heartbleed.nse:205>
 (...tail calls...)

 Completed NSE at 08:28, 0.01s elapsed
```

The host I scanned sits on public IP space so I know it's not a FW issue. I also am the owner of the files and have execute perms for the script.

Comment: If I look at line 77 of the script I see an stdnse.keys reference. The line reads ["ciphers"] = stdnse.keys(tls.CIPHERS), I did some digging which led me back to the stdnse.lua file, which does have a "keys" function, but I am not sure the two are related or what to do with it if it is. I may be way off here but just wanted to add that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this script, and my official guide is [available here](https://gist.github.com/bonsaiviking/10402038). The simplest solution is to upgrade to [the latest Nmap](http://nmap.org/download) (version 6.47 as of this writing).

Comment: Thanks I'll go this route. I was under the impression however that installing packages outside of the normal pkg install (apt-get) method was frowned in Ubuntu. Is there something I need to know after I install this new nmap in order for the system to call it and not the old nmap? Just remove the old nmap?

Comment: @user53029 I'd recommend removing the old one, as long as you have the required dependencies. I use [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) to make dpkg manage it and allow easy removal and upgrades. Just be sure to `apt-get install libssl-dev` before you build; all other build dependencies should be included (apart from a compiler, of course!).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by updating to the latest version of nmap. You can add `pi-rho`s ppa to apt-get the latest version of nmap.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pi-rho/security
sudo apt-get update
```

And then,

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```